# Xpath error with object of class XMLDocumentContent

Tags: xml, r, xpath, rcurl

I just got started with the RCurl package and after reading about the basics of xpath I tried to solve a simple example. What I'd like to do is to retrieve all the tables from a local sports site. I used the following code:

```
# used packages
library(Rcurl)
library(XML)

# retrieve
test <- getURL(url = "http://sporza.be/cm/sporza/voetbal/Jupiler_Pro_League")

# parse
test <- htmlTreeParse(test)

# select tables
tabel <- xpathApply(test, "//table", xmlValue)
```

When I run this piece of code I always encounter the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "XMLDocumentContent"
```

I seem to be missing something very basic but I can't seem to see what exactly.

Comment: I'd recommend at least looking at the xml2 package which eliminates many of these needless inconsistencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xpathApply` does not work on XMLDocumentContent objects but does with on XMLNodes. You can extract the root node of your xml document with `xmlRoot` and then make xpath queries against that object

```
table <- xpathApply(xmlRoot(test), "//table", xmlValue)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I'm disappointed I didn't notice this mistake myself.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

```
library(rvest)
all_table1<-"http://sporza.be/cm/sporza/voetbal/Jupiler_Pro_League" %>%
            html%>%
            html_table()
```

## Solution 2

```
library(XML)
all_table2<-readHTMLTable(htmlParse("http://sporza.be/cm/sporza/voetbal/Jupiler_Pro_League"))
```

Comment: readHTMLTable() works fine in this context but I was looking for a more general solution (but failed to mention this in my opening post so my bad).